# Union nested in a structure returning garbage value

Tags: c

Everything is working fine, except the nested union is not getting updated. I am using mingw compiler.
I was just learning coding regarding C and trying out nested union and other stuff when this problem came up. Please tell me WHAT IS THE ERROR of the code, along with possible debugging. I couldn't find anything wrong with it.

Output:

a:3

b:3

l.a: 8

l.b: 5

union: -536870912

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
} two;

typedef union
{
 int c;
 float d;
} ad;

typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
 two l;
 ad n; /*This is nested union that is not getting updated*/
} one;

void trr(one *p);

int main()
{
 one tr={2,3,{4,5},{.d=5.43}}; 
 trr(&tr);
 printf("a: %d\nb: %d\nl.a: %d\nl.b: %d\nunion: %d",tr.a,tr.b,tr.l.a,tr.l.b,tr.n.d);
 return 0;
}

void trr(one *p)
{
 p->a=(*p).a+1;
 p->l.a=p->l.a*2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr.n.d` has type `float`.  The `%d` format specifier tells `printf` to treat it as `int` however.  Try changing your format specifier to `%f` instead

```
printf("a: %d\nb: %d\nl.a: %d\nl.b: %d\nunion: %f"
//                                              ^
```

Alternatively, you could initialise the `int` member of your union:

```
one tr={2,3,{4,5},{.c=42}};
```

Comment: Can you explain why the code from OP results in printing a randomly, undefined value for float? I assume printf wants to read 4 bytes integer data from the stack but there is float data instead. I also assume the length of float data is greater or equal the length of int data. So, why isn't the print result always the same for that float value?

Comment: @jewirth You're correct - `printf` reads `sizeof(int)` bytes and interprets that memory as `int`.  `sizeof(float)` may well be the same but the use of the bits is different between `float` and `int`.  My reading of the question is that the same value was always printed - this value just wasn't what the OP expected.